# Osculating circle

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, conic-sections

Compute the radius of osculating circle of the hyperbola $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ at one of its vertices and give a geometrical method for the construction of this osculating circle. Consider the particular case of equilateral hyperbola $x^2-y^2=a^2$

I computed the radius on the vertex $(a,0)$ by finding the reciprocal of the curvature of hyperbola. Which is $r=\frac{1}{|\kappa|}=\frac {b^2}{a}. \ $

Now how can I solve the next part? "give a geometrical method for the construction of this osculating circle"

Comment: It is not clear what is being asked.  Perhaps you could describe the context in which this problem arose: is it from a book? what book? are you taking a course? what topics are covered in the course?

Comment: @MatthewConroy It is from a book on Differential geometry

Comment: Great, thanks. It never hurts to give more details: what book? what page? was this problem assigned to you by a person you can ask for clarification, or are you just doing it on your own? Sharing details is always good.

Comment: @MatthewConroy the book is "lectures on classical differential geometry" by Paul A Blaga page no is 109 problem no 46 I am just doing it on my own.

Comment: Thanks for adding more details.  I looked at the pdf and I agree it is not clear what is being asked for.  Perhaps a geometer and chime in. http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~pablaga/geometrie%20III/Blaga%20P.-Lectures%20on%20the%20differential%20geometry%20of%20curves%20and%20surfaces%20(2005).pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the particular case of the equilateral hyperbola
$$
x^{2} - y^{2} = a^{2},
$$
the center of the osculating circle is
$$
\left(a + \frac{b^{2}}{a}, 0\right) = (2a, 0),
$$
and the radius is $a$. Let $O$ be the origin (where the hyperbola's axes (and asymptotes) cross) and $V$ the vertex $(a, 0)$. Draw a circle of center $V$ through $O$, and let $P$ be the point diametrically opposite this circle on the axis. The osculating circle has center $P$ and passes through $V$.

[image: Constructing an osculating circle to an equilateral hyperbola]

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \alpha (t)=(x(t),y(t))$ is a regular parametrization of hyperbola, then the center of osculating circle at a point t is given by $$C (t) =\alpha (t) + \frac{1}{\kappa}N(t)$$,where $\kappa$ is the curvature of $\alpha$, and $N$ is unit  normal vector field of $\alpha$.

Osculating circle approximates the curve in the neighborhood of a point, and you want the circle and the curve to have the same tangent vector and normal vector and, of course, the same curvature.

You have the center and radius of a circle, I think that's enough.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I find normal vector field?

Comment: @hitman What do you know about curves so far? It's a bit strange to know what curvature is and not to know what normal vector is. Don't get me wrong, I'm not judging you, but I'm interested to know how you defined curvature and the other things so that I can make this story a bit shorter.

Comment: I know about the normal vector but you said that it is normal vector field. And as far as I know vector field is different  than a vector so I thought normal vector field is different than normal vector.

Comment: And to find curvature I first took the first and second derivative of the set of parametric equation of the given hyperbola. Then used the formula to find the curvature at the vertex

Comment: Well (if I've translated it well), that's basically the same thing. If curve is a function from interval I then normal vector field is a function that assigns normal vector N(t) to every point t from I. You already know how to find it.

Comment: It's just a different term. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Its okay. And thank you

Comment: $$ C(0)=(a,0)+\frac{b^2}{a} \ \ (\frac{q}{a},0)=(a+\frac{b^2}{a^2},0)$$ Is it correct?

Comment: Curvature is fine, but are you sure about normal vector? What is q? I calculated $$ C(0)=(a,0) +\frac{b^2}{a} (1,0)=(a+\frac{b^2}{a},0)$$.

Comment: It is not q it is b

Comment: Even then something's wrong. Look what you've written.

Comment: Normal vector should be a unit vector.

Comment: Please tell me that whether N(t) is unit normal vector or normal vector because if it is just normal vector then it should be the vector that i wrote but if it is unit normal vector then yours is correct.

Comment: N is normal vector and it's norm is 1.

Comment: The reason you are calculating center this way is that you want to move from a point of the curve, where circle touches it, in the direction of N, until you get to the center. If N is unit vector, then you shoud move radius times N, which is $\frac{1}{\kappa} N$. If N isn't a unit vector then the formula I've given you doesn't hold.

Comment: Then i think we should say that N is unit normal vector...  If we say this then the vector we get is certainly unit vector

Comment: You're right, I've edited it. I hope I've managed to explain why that's important.